# why does the rails console break my shell when I send to background?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This happens in some projects, but I haven't found the reason why it does it. If I open a rails console then send it to the background, it appears to keep running but takes only the first character I type as a command and return with `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'w/e' for main:Object`

for instance this...

```
bash-3.2$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
irb(main):001:0> 
[1]+  Stopped                 rails c
bash-3.2$ ls
NameError: undefined local variable or method `l' for main:Object
from (irb):1
from /Users/geerm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /Users/geerm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/geerm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /Users/geerm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/geerm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/geerm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/geerm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /Users/geerm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/geerm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/geerm/Sites/siece/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: The rails console is not meant to be run as a background process.

Comment: that doesn't mean it cant be :), it can be handy to just put it away to run a quick command and bring it back

Comment: Though you're right, it's not in the background, it's stopped.